# Create Email and Attach Selected Email

Tags: vba, outlook

I create a new email with the code below.

I'd like to have an attachment. I think I have to use an `OutMail.Attachment.Method` but the attachment needs to be a specific email.

I want the entire email with contents (ie. texts, files, pics, etc.) as the attachment.

I'd like to attach whatever email I have highlighted (as an .msg).

```vb
Public Sub RemarkRequest()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Signature As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next

'Get the user signature
With OutMail
    .Display
End With
   
Signature = OutMail.HTMLBody

'Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.
With OutMail
    .To = "yyy@bbb.com; zzz@bbb.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Subject"
    .HTMLBody = "Text" & Signature
    .Display
End With

On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Example will be -

```
'// Forces explicit declaration of all variables in a file
Option Explicit
Sub ForwardAsAttchment()
    '//  Declare variables
    Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olSignature As String

    On Error Resume Next
    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No Item selected")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        Set olMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        '// Get the user signature
        With olMsg
            .Display
        End With

        olSignature = olMsg.HTMLBody

        '// Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.
        With olMsg
            .Attachments.Add olItem, olEmbeddeditem ' Attch Selected email
            .Subject = "Subject"
            .To = "yyy@bbb.com; zzz@bbb.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .HTMLBody = "Text" & olSignature
            .Display
        '    .Send
        End With
    Next
    '// Clean up
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set olMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```